# Is Spring Data JPA really that easy to use

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have been working with Spring and recently discovered the existence of the PersistantContext and EntityManagers and so forth. I have always worked with Spring Data + JPA so i have never really come to much in contact with thees things. After looking around how Hibernate does it with Session's and JPA alone does it with EntityManager it kinda freaked me out. So i was wondering how Spring Data JPA does all the persisting and manipulation with the enteties. All there was in the documentation was this:

> https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.entity-persistence

So mainly my questions is does Spring Data JPA really make interacting with the database that easy ? A few easy questions:

1. If im using classic JPA repositories and Spring data. Would something like this work flawlessly :

   personRepoistory.save(someperson); //His name is fred
   Person temp=personRepository.findByName("Fred);
   temp.setName("Freddy");
   personRepostiory.save(temp);

Would this be essentially an update of the person?

2. Will i need any knowledge of manipulating the entities with a Spring Data JPA entityManager and can you list some cases where i might need that?

Comment: If you're going to ask a question about "Spring Data JPA" then you ought to know by now that it is != JPA API, so tag the question correctly and actually include `spring-data-jpa` instead of `jpa`

Answer (score 1):

**Reduces boilerplate code:**
A fineder method implemented with your own repository would consist of several lines of source code. One line creating the query, second line initialising it, third line passing the parameters , forth line collecting the result.

**Flexibility:**
Allows for inlining custom repository code with spring data managed repository methods. This allows.

**Provides Generic implementation to common problems:**
For example pagination with spring data comes for free. How much code and how much bugs would you produce to get this on your own ?

**Futher integration with Spring MVC:**
Spares even more boilerplate code by providing transparent integration into the Spring MVC ecosystem.

**Forces you to use a sensibly named interface:**
Here I would point to the "Dynamic query derivation from repository method names". Which has consequences over you interface naming and structure.

Is it easy ? Obviously it is one more technical abstraction on top of JPA and hibernate if you are using hibernate, but at the same time the amount of code you would save and the amount of bugs you would have spared. Yes it may be a good tradeoff.

Comment: I know it has a lot of benefits, i was just wondering about the persistance and transaction aspect that other technologies have to worry about

Comment: @Emperor You will benefit from understanding how JPA and hibernate works. Spring jpa is only abstraction on top of this two concepts. A way to build your API if you want.